# how to get the file size in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload

i created a form in jsp which containing some properties about the file like file category, file language,etc after submitting the button form variable redirect to servlet,in this servlet i want to know the file size.

Comment: generally u can't do that, unless u post the file to the server, if the file is huge, say 1G, this is very impractical, you may want to consider some client side solution, like use an swf to query the file size

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Common's FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) and [`fileItem.getSize()`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getSize%28%29)

Comment: my form look like <form name="" action=""><input type="file" value="fileid"/><itnput type="text" value="language"><input type="submit"></form> then how i get the file size

Comment: Please refer this [quick tutorial](http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet-file-upload-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to [HTML Form Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html), you need to set the request method to POST and the request encoding to multipart/form-data in the  element. If you are using Servlet API 2.5 or earlier, you will have to parse the request yourselves.[Apache File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) API does a good job at that and you can easily get the size of the file. However in case you are using Servlet 3.0 API, the you can use the Servlet API for parsing. You can find the code snippet [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html)

Comment: Please try to use your own words instead of copypasting/rewriting other's answer :) At any way, this does not answer the concrete quesiton at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the servlet you can get the uploaded file size as follows

```
Part filePart = request.getPart("inputFile");
long fileSize = part.getSize();
```